# Git alias referencing commands executed from a subdirectory of a repo

Tags: bash, git, git-alias

Two git functions defined in .gitconfig (using alias)

> create-file = "!f() { for name in \"$@\"; do echo $name>$name.txt; done; }; f"
>
> m-commit = "!f() { for name in \"$@\"; do git create-file $name; done; }; f"

git m-commit a b c

This runs ok from the top-level directory of a git repo.

How to make it to run it from subdirectory, (to create test files in this subdirectory, not in the top)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why don't you just `alias m-commit="for name in \"$@\"; do echo $name>$name.txt; done;"` in bash?

Comment: Besides, you'd better provide something about the actual occurrence when you run it in subdirectory.

Comment: Yeah, there is no reason for either command to be a Git alias; the former doesn't use Git at all and the latter only does because `create-file` is a Git alias.

Comment: If I update create-file = "!createFile() { for name in \"$@\"; do echo $name>\"${GIT_PREFIX:-.}\"/$name.txt; done; }; createFile" this will work as git create_file a b c - but still not as git m_commit a b c - as files will be still created in the top directory. This excise is educational, to commit many simple files in any sub directories of the repo.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the top-level directory is output by `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`.